# jQgrid, validation in search dialog

Tags: jqgrid

Anybody know how to use validation in custom search dialog that looks like validation in edit/add forms?

Comment: What kind of validation are you looking for? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote [the answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074429/validation-before-submitting-the-search-form-generated-using-filtergrid-in-jqgrid/4078683#4078683) so that it can help you in solving of the problem also.