# Is it possible to bind multiple event handlers to JqGrid events without overwriting previous ones?

Tags: javascript, events, jqgrid, jquery

For example, I call my default settings on every page load and bind a function to loadComplete to do some basic formatting for my grids.

On some pages, I have additional logic I would like to execute at the same time, but if I set loadComplete in the grid definition, it will overwrite the function set in my defaults.

Is there a way to bind multiple handlers, or some other way of executing all the necessary code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you ask about an important problem existing in the current version of jqGrid. It's difficult to implement more as one [event handler](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) in jqGrid now. The problem is not important for small projects where you use jqGrid, but can be important in case that you want construct some classes which interprets jqGrid. Your current workaround is OK, but have the restriction which you understand yourself. The main problem that in the way you can implement **only one** more additional `loadCompleteEx` handler.

What I would suggest you is the usage of [jQuery.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or better [jQuery.triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/). You can use it together with [jQuery.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [jQuery.unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/). In the way you can define any number of event handlers which works like standard jQuery events.

For example,

```
var grid = $("#list");

grid.bind('jqGridLoadComplete',function(e,data) {
    alert ("in first jqGridLoadComplete event handler. Called for the page " +
           data.page);
});
grid.jqGrid({
    // jqGrid parameters
    // ...
    loadComplete: function(data) {
        alert("main load complete");
        $(this).triggerHandler("jqGridLoadComplete", data);
    }
});
grid.bind('jqGridLoadComplete.jqGrid',function(e,data) {
    alert ("in second jqGridLoadComplete event handler. Called for the page " +
           data.page);
});
```

In the second `jQuery.bind` I used namespaced event 'jqGridLoadComplete.jqGrid' from the namespace 'jqGrid'. So you can use everything which you know (and which you need) about standard events in jQuery.

See the corresponding demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithLoadCompleteTrigger.htm). Try to switch the pages in the grid or change the sorting to call `loadComplete`.

I bind the second `jqGridLoadComplete` *after* the jqGrid definition. Because my demo uses `datatype:'local'` the first call of `loadComplete` will be *before* the binding executed. So at the first `loadComplete` execution will be the second `jqGridLoadComplete` event handler not called. So you should better to bind your event handler before the jqGrid definition. In the case you can be sure that the event will be always called.

**UPDATED:** **IMPORTANT!!!**. One **don't need to trigger `jqGridLoadComplete` event explicitly** inside of `loadComplete` if you use the current version of jqGrid. jqGrid **do this already for you**. The above code was written **before** the corresponding functionality are included in the main code of jqGrid. The answer just described the main idea *how* multiple event handlers could be implemented in jqGrid. After writing the answer I posted some pull requests to trirand with my suggestion to implement jQuery events in jqGrid. Starting with the version 4.3.2 (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_triggered_events_new_in_v4.3.2)) jqGrid support the events.

Comment: Would a potentially simpler solution be using my response with an array of functions, executing all of them in sequence? I'm guessing it's more conventional/better practice to utilize the `bind` functions.

Comment: @IronicMuffin: There are different small subquestions and different kinds of usage which are possible. The `bind` method uses `jQuery.data` with `events` as the key. The value has `jqGridLoadComplete` as an array (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074429/validation-before-submitting-the-search-form-generated-using-filtergrid-in-jqgrid/4078683#4078683)). If you just use `loadCompleteEx` as array yourself you can implement the current workaround, but you should be careful. Where allocate the array? Will it work with more as one grid and so on. I find the "trigger"-way more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do something before the request use the beforeRequest function.

you can also bind a function to the gridComplete option.  could you give a code example to show what you are trying to do?

Comment: gridComplete only fires once, and if I have formatting I need done on every load, then that won't work. For example, I have a custom message I show if the grid is empty. I have to check for that on every load. Now, if I want to do additional logic for an empty grid, I can't just add to loadComplete, because it overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

My hackaround solution:

```
// Global Variable in my common.js
var loadCompleteEx;

// set defaults
$.extend($.jgrid.defaults, {
     datatype: 'json',
     height: "100%",
     ...
     loadComplete: function () {
         if ($("#grid").getGridParam("reccount") === 0)
            $("#empty-grid-message").show();
         else
            $("#empty-grid-message").hide();

         // if loadCompleteEx is defined, call it at the end of loadComplete
         if (loadCompleteEx)
             loadCompleteEx();
      }
}

// In my specific page js
loadCompleteEx = function () {
    // Do more stuff after load completes
};
```

Works like a charm...is there any bad practice in here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier solution to this than I have seen recommended anywhere else:

```
// Set defaults
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.defaults, {
    loadComplete: function () {
        myCustomFunction();
    }
});

loadComplete: function() {
    // someOtherFunction();
    $.jgrid.defaults.loadComplete(); // Runs myCustomFunction()
},
```