# Coloring a row depending on value trirand jqgrid

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I need to color the background of a row depending on the value stored in a database. I'm using TriRand jqgrid. I need to get the value from POLineStatus and if it equals 2 I need to color the background red. I setup a class in the css file that will get the proper background-color property. Unfortunately I cannot figure out how to get it to do this on a per column basis.

```
$mycellattr =  <<<CELLATTR
function (rowid, value, rawObject, colModel, arraydata){ 
    if(value=="Rejected"){
    return {class:'colorClass'};
   }
}
CELLATTR;


$grid->setGridEvent('rowattr', $mycellattr);
```

gridViewSubGrid.php
-------- Full code:

```
<?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
}

 $user = $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];

require_once "model.php"; 

require_once "jq-configSub.php";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName1, $connectionInfo1);

// include the jqGrid Class
require_once "php/jqGrid.php";

// include the SQLSRV driver class
require_once "php/jqGridSqlsrv.php";

// include the autocomplete class 
require_once "php/jqAutocomplete.php"; 

// include the datepicker class 
require_once "php/jqCalendar.php"; 

if(isset ($_REQUEST["CustPOID"])){
    $rowid = jqGridUtils::Strip($_REQUEST["CustPOID"]);
    }
else{
    $rowid = "";
}

$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);

$grid->SelectCommand = "SELECT [CustPOLineID]
      ,[Qty]
      ,[Price]
      ,[POLineComment]
      ,[Cost]
      ,[Origin]
      ,[POLineLoadDate]
      ,[ApptNum]
      ,[CreateDate]
      ,[VendRefNum]
      ,[HapcoPONum]
      ,[PriceAlt]
      ,[VendRefNumAlt]
      ,[MiscCharge]
      ,[PHDSCharge]
      ,[VBRCharge]
      ,[CostAlt]
      ,[VendAlt]
      ,[LineGM]
      ,[ModifyDate]
      ,[ModifiedBy]
      ,[CreatedBy]
      ,[VendPurchPONum]
      ,[CustPOID]
      ,cpl.VendId
      ,vn.VendDesc
      ,cpl.ProdID
      ,pd.ProdDesc
      ,cpl.POLineStatusID
      ,posl.POLineStatusDesc
      ,cpl.ChargeTypeID
      ,ct.ChargeTypeDesc
      ,cpl.AlertReasonID
      ,ar.AlertReasonCode
  FROM [HapcoSales].[dbo].[CustPOLine] as cpl 

                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor as vn
                                            on cpl.VendId  = vn.VendId
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Product as pd
                                            on cpl.ProdID  = pd.ProdID
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN POLineStatus as posl
                                            on cpl.POLineStatusID  = posl.POLineStatusID
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN ChargeType as ct
                                            on cpl.ChargeTypeID  = ct.ChargeTypeID
                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN AlertReason as ar
                                            on cpl.AlertReasonID  = ar.AlertReasonID
 WHERE CustPOID= ?";
// set the ouput format to json 
$grid->dataType = 'json'; 
$grid->table ="CustPOLine"; 
//Set primary key
$grid->setPrimaryKeyId("CustPOLineID"); 
$grid->setDbDate('Y-m-d'); 
$grid->setDbTime('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$grid->setUserDate('m/d/Y');
$grid->setUserTime('m/d/Y');
$grid->datearray = array('POLineLoadDate');




$Model = array(   
array("name"=>"CustPOLineID","editable"=>false,"hidden"=>true), 
array("name"=>"Qty", "label"=>"Qty:", "width"=>"50","editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>1)),
array("name"=>"ProdDesc", "label"=>"Item:","width"=>"350","editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>2)),
array("name"=>"ProdID","label"=>"Product ID:","hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("readonly"=>"readonly")),
array("name"=>"Price", "label"=>"Price:","width"=>"75","formatter"=>"currency","formatoptions"=>array("decimalPlaces"=>2,"thousandsSeparator"=>",","prefix"=>"$"),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>3)),
array("name"=>"Cost", "label"=>"Cost:","width"=>"75","formatter"=>"currency","formatter"=>"currency","formatoptions"=>array("decimalPlaces"=>2,"thousandsSeparator"=>",","prefix"=>"$"),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>4)),
array("name"=>"VendDesc", "label"=>"Vendor:","width"=>"300","editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>5)),
array("name"=>"VendId", "label"=>"Vendor ID:","hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("readonly"=>"readonly")),
array("name"=>"MiscCharge","formatter"=>"currency","formatter"=>"currency","formatoptions"=>array("decimalPlaces"=>2,"thousandsSeparator"=>",","prefix"=>"$"),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>6)),
array("name"=>"PHDSCharge","formatter"=>"currency","formatter"=>"currency","formatoptions"=>array("decimalPlaces"=>2,"thousandsSeparator"=>",","prefix"=>"$"),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>7)),
array("name"=>"VBRCharge","formatter"=>"currency","formatter"=>"currency","formatoptions"=>array("decimalPlaces"=>2,"thousandsSeparator"=>",","prefix"=>"$"),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>8)),
array("name"=>"POLineLoadDate","label"=>"Load Date:","width"=>"125","editable"=>true,"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>9)),
array("name"=>"POLineComment","search"=>false,"width"=>"300","formatter"=>"textarea","label"=>"Comments","edittype"=>"textarea","editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>10)),
array("name"=>"PriceAlt","label"=>"Alt Price:", "formatter"=>"currency","formatter"=>"currency","formatoptions"=>array("decimalPlaces"=>2,"thousandsSeparator"=>",","prefix"=>"$"),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>11)),
array("name"=>"CostAlt", "label"=>"Alt Cost:","formatter"=>"currency","formatter"=>"currency","formatoptions"=>array("decimalPlaces"=>2,"thousandsSeparator"=>",","prefix"=>"$"),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>12)),
array("name"=>"VendAlt", "label"=>"Alt Vendor:","editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>13)),
array("name"=>"ChargeTypeID", "label"=>"Charge Type","editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>14)),
array("name"=>"ModifyDate", "label"=>"Modified:","formoptions"=>array("rowpos"=>2,"colpos"=>4),"editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("readonly"=>"readonly")),
array("name"=>"ModifiedBy", "label"=>"Modified By:","formoptions"=>array("rowpos"=>3,"colpos"=>4),"editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("readonly"=>"readonly")),
array("name"=>"CreatedBy","label"=>"Created By:","formoptions"=>array("rowpos"=>4,"colpos"=>4),"editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("readonly"=>"readonly")),
array("name"=>"HapcoPONum","formoptions"=>array("rowpos"=>2,"colpos"=>3),"editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>21)),
array("name"=>"Origin","formoptions"=>array("rowpos"=>3,"colpos"=>3),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>22)),
array("name"=>"VendRefNumAlt","formoptions"=>array("rowpos"=>4,"colpos"=>3),"editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>23)),
array("name"=>"ApptNum","editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>15)),
array("name"=>"VendRefNum","editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true) ,"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>16)),
array("name"=>"VendPurchPONum","editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>17)),
array("name"=>"AlertReasonCode","editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>18)),
array("name"=>"AlertReasonID","editable"=>true,"hidden"=>true, "editrules"=>array("edithidden"=>true),"editoptions"=>array("tabindex"=>19)),
array("name"=>"POLineStatusDesc"),
array("name"=>"POLineStatusID"),
array("name"=>"LineGM", "label"=>"Gross Margin:", "editable"=>true,"editoptions"=>array("readonly"=>"readonly"),"formatter"=>"currency","formatter"=>"currency","formatoptions"=>array("decimalPlaces"=>2,"thousandsSeparator"=>",","prefix"=>"$")),
array("name"=>"CustPOID","hidden"=>true)
                    );

$grid->setColModel($Model, array(&$rowid));

$grid->setUrl('gridViewSubGrid.php');

$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "hoverrows"=>true,
    "resizable"=>true,
    "scroll"=>1,//unlimited scroll
    "rowNum"=>100,//100 entries on load
    "caption"=>"Detailed view of each sale.",
    "rowList"=>array(10,20,30),
    "sortname"=>"CustPOLineID",//sort by
    "sortorder"=>"desc",
    "autowidth"=>true,//determine the users screen resolution, generate grid off of that
    "height"=>"175",
    "footerrow"=>true,
    "userDataOnFooter"=>true

    ));
$grid->setDatePicker("POLineLoadDate",null,true,false);
$grid->setColProperty("POLineLoadDate",array( 
    "formatter"=>"date", 
    "formatoptions"=>array("srcformat"=>"Y-m-d H:i:s","newformat"=>"m/d/Y") 
    ) 
); 

$grid->setColProperty("CustPOID", array("hidden"=>true));
$grid->setColProperty("CustPOLineID", array("hidden"=>true));


$grid->setAutocomplete("VendDesc","#VendId","SELECT DISTINCT VendDesc, VendDesc as VendDesc2, VendId FROM Vendor WHERE VendDesc LIKE ? ORDER BY VendDesc",null,true,false);

$grid->setAutocomplete("ProdDesc","#ProdID","SELECT ProdDesc, ProdDesc AS ProdDesc2, ProdID FROM Product WHERE ProdDesc LIKE ? ORDER BY ProdDesc",null,true,false);

$grid->setSelect("POLineStatusID", "SELECT DISTINCT POLineStatusID, POLineStatusDesc, POLineStatusID AS POLineStatusDesc FROM POLineStatus ORDER BY 1",false,true,true,array(""=>"All"));


$grid->setSelect("ChargeTypeID", "SELECT DISTINCT ChargeTypeID, ChargeTypeDesc, ChargeTypeID AS ChargeTypeDesc FROM ChargeType ORDER BY 1",false,true,true,array(""=>"All"));
//We select the key:value for the select drop downs
$grid->setSelect("AlertReasonID", "SELECT DISTINCT AlertReasonID,AlertReasonDesc, AlertReasonID AS AlertReasonDesc FROM AlertReason ORDER BY 1",false,true,true,array(""=>"All"));


// Enable toolbar searching 
$grid->navigator = true; 
$grid->setNavOptions('navigator', array("excel"=>true,"add"=>true,"edit"=>true,"del"=>true,"view"=>true));
$grid->setNavOptions('edit', array("closeAfterEdit"=>true,"height"=>"auto","dataheight"=>"auto", "width"=>"auto")); 
$grid->setNavOptions('add', array("height"=>"auto","dataheight"=>"auto","width"=>"auto")); 



// disable the CRUD buttons when we initialy load the grid
$initgrid = <<<INIT
jQuery("#add_detail").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
jQuery("#edit_detail").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
jQuery("#del_detail").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
INIT;

// on beforeshow form when add we get the customer id and set it for posting
$beforeshow = <<<BEFORE
function(formid)
{
var srow = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
if(srow) {
    var gridrow = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getRowData',srow);
    $("#CustPOID",formid).val(gridrow.CustPOID);
}
}
BEFORE;
//This function brings up the edit dialog on a double click

$dbClk = <<<ONDBLCLK
function dbClk(rowid, selected)
{
jQuery(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid, {"height" : "100%","width" : "100%", "dataheight" : "auto"});
}
ONDBLCLK;

$mycellattr =  <<<CELLATTR
            function (e, rd) {
                if (rd.POLineStatusID === "2") { // test the value of POLineStatus column
                    return {"class": "colorClass"};
                }

            }
CELLATTR;


$grid->setGridEvent('rowattr', $mycellattr);
//$grid->setColProperty('POLineStatusID', array("cellattr"=>"js:".$mycellattr));

//$grid->customFunc = "gmCalc";

$grid->setGridEvent('ondblClickRow', $dbClk);
$grid->setNavEvent('add', 'beforeShowForm', $beforeshow); 

$cid = jqGridUtils::GetParam('CustPOLineID'); //we get the CustPOLineID from the SQL query

//$grid->setAfterCrudAction('add', "UPDATE CustPOLine SET LineGM = 3240 WHERE CustPOLineID=?",array($cid));
$dateNow=dateTimeNow(); //goes out to model.php and calls the dateTimeNow function - and returns current value
$grid->setAfterCrudAction('edit', "UPDATE CustPOLine SET ModifiedBy = '".$user."' WHERE CustPOLineID=?",array($cid));
$grid->setAfterCrudAction('edit', "UPDATE CustPOLine SET ModifyDate = '".$dateNow."' WHERE CustPOLineID=?",array($cid));

$summaryrows = array("LineGM"=>array("LineGM"=>"SUM"));


$grid->renderGrid("#detail","#pgdetail", true, $summaryrows, array(&$rowid), true,true);
$conn = null;


function gmCalc($gdata, $conn)
{
// gdata->rows contain the grid data rows
   foreach($gdata->rows as $row ) 
   {
     //$total = ((($Price * $Qty)-($Cost * $Qty))-(($MiscCharge+$PHDSCharge+$VBRCharge)*$Qty));
     $row->LineGM = ((($row->Price*$row->Qty)-($row->Cost*$row->Qty))-(($row->MiscCharge+$row->PHDSCharge+$row->VBRCharge)*$row->Qty));
   }
   // return the modified
   return $gdata;
}

?>
```

------index.php

```
<?php 
    require_once ('model.php');
    loginCheck();
    require_once ('header.php'); 


?>

    <div id="main-container">
        <div id="mainContainer" class="wrapper clearfix">
            <div>
                <?php include "gridView.php";?>
            </div>  
                <div>
                <?php include "gridViewSubGrid.php"; ?>
                </div>


                  <h2>Gross Margin:</h2>
                  <div>From: <input type="text" id="from" >
                         To: <input type="text" id="to" onchange="setFrom()"></div>
                    <div id="myDiv"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div id="griddef"></div> 
        </div> <!-- #main -->
    </div> <br><!-- #main-container -->
<?php require_once ('footer.php'); ?>
```

-------Olegs fix:

```
$mycellattr =  <<<CELLATTR
function (rd,cur,id){ 
    if(rd.POLineStatusID=="2"){
    return {"class":"colorClass"};
   }
}
CELLATTR;


$grid->setGridEvent('rowattr', $mycellattr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a PHP developer, but what is definitively wrong in your code is the parameters of `rowattr`. It has tree parameters `rd`, `cur` and `id`. One needs only the first parameter in the most cases. Look in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) for a code example.

Alternatively you can use `jqGridRowAttr` jQuery event. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778789/315935) for code examples. In your case it will be

```
$("#list").bind("jqGridRowAttr", function (e, rd) {
    if (rd.POLineStatus === "Rejected") { // test the value of POLineStatus column
        return {"class": "colorClass"};
    }
});
```

It's important to use `{"class": "colorClass"}` instead of `{class: "colorClass"}` to be compatible with old versions of Internet Explorer. It's important to set the `bind` **before** the grid will be created.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridRowAttr.htm) demonstrates the usage of "jqGridRowAttr".

Comment: Oleg, thank you for taking the time to respond. My only issue is, I don't setup my grid the way you do. It's some proprietary way TriRand setup it seems. For instance, I'll show you my code. I edited my original post and put it up top again.

Comment: @Waragi: You are welcome! Your problem was that you used `if(value=="Rejected")` where `value` is the second parameter of `rowattr`. It was wrong. I wrote you about two ways to fix the problem: one with fixing of the code of `rowattr` and another with usage of `$("#detail").bind("jqGridRowAttr", ...);`. For the second way you need understand how to mix JavaScript code with PHP code (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.net/documentation/php/_2v90ju98u.htm)). You last code is better but still wrong. You use `function (e, rd)` instead of `function (rd)` in `$mycellattr`.

Comment: @Waragi: The definition of CSS rule for the class `colorClass` could be another point of error. If you will not have correct results after fixing of `$mycellattr` you should verify (and post) the CSS rule.

Comment: You are a saint, it's been over five hours - it's working! You're right, I need to understand how to mix PHP and javascript better. Thank you again